# Continuity of function consisting of an infinite series.

Tags: integration, summation, continuity

> Let $f(x) , 0\leq x\leq 1$ be defined by,
>
> $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}$$.
>
> Show that $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and that,
>
> $$\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$$.

I have never dealt with functions which are infinite series.

How do I approach this type of thing? Can I just ignore the sum and see if $\frac{1}{(x+n)^2}$ is continuous on the interval?

But then again, I wouldn't how to go for the integral with that mindset.

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: You want to show the sum is _uniformly_ convergent on $[0,1]$. The notion of uniform convergence is probably in the book, somewhere shortly before this exercise. Probably a thing called the "M-test" is also in the book; you can use that. Then you can use the theorem from the book that a uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. And also the theorem that if a sum is uniformly convergent then the integral of the sum is the sum of the integrals. (Then you calculate those integrals and you get a telescoping series).

Comment: What book are you referring to?

Comment: The book where the exercise came from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}.
$$
Then, for every $x\in [0,1]$ we have
$$
|f(x)-f_n(x)|=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2}.
$$
It follows that
$$
\|f-f_n\|_\infty\le \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2} \to 0 \mbox{ as } n \to \infty,
$$
i.e. $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, and therefore $f\in C([0,1])$ because each $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Since the convergence $f_n\to f$ is uniform on $[0,1]$, we have:
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx.
$$
For every $n$ we have
$$
\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=\sum_{k=1}^n\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x+k)^2}\,dx=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x+k}\Big|_0^1=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)=1-\frac{1}{n+1},
$$
and taking the limit we get:
$$
\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)=1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The [Weierstrass M-Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) says that the series $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}$ converges uniformly for $x \in [0,1]$. Moreover, since the partial sums of this series are continuous on $[0,1]$, the limit $f$ must be continuous there as well.

In order to compute the integral, we can interchange the integral and the sum to see that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(x+n)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( -\frac{1}{(x+n)} \bigg|_0^1 \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) = 1,
$$
where the last sum is telescoping and so it is easily evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to demonstrate that the limiting function is continuous, you can show that it is the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions.

The sequence of functions here is straight forward: $$f_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N (x+n)^{-2}.$$

We wish to show that these functions converge to our limiting function uniformly.

Note that for each $n$ we have $(x+n)^{-2} \le n^{-2}$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Thus the series is bounded above by $\sum n^{-2}$ at each point and converges by the monotone convergence theorem.

To demonstrate that the convergence is uniform, we need to show that the remainder can be bounded by a function going to zero as a function of $N$ and independent of $x$.

$$|f(x) - f_N(x)| = \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+n)^2}  \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$ converges, we know that the sum on the right tends to zero as $N\to \infty$. Thus $f$ is the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions and is itself uniformly convergent.

---

As for the integral, since the sequence $f_N$ is uniformly convergent, we can exchange integration and the limit: $$\int_0^1 f(x) dx = \int_0^1 \lim_{N\to \infty} f_N(x) dx = \lim_{N\to \infty} \int_0^1 f_N(x)dx = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(x+n)^2} dx$$ $$=\lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right).$$

This series telescopes to $1$.