# Let $f$ be (Riemann) integrable over $[0,1]$. Show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x^n}f(t)dt$ is continuous on $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, riemann-integration

Problem: Let $f$ be (Riemann) integrable over $[0,1]$. Show $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{x^n}f(t)dt$ is continuous on $(0,1)$.

I know that if $f$ is (Riemann) integrable over $[0,1]$, since $x \in (0,1)$ then $x^n \in (0,1)$ also and every integral exists. Clearly the integral eventually goes to $0$ but I'm not sure how to use that. Also, I know that given an $f(t)$, I can use the epsilon-delta definition of continuity to show it's continuous, but here I'm only given that it's Riemann integrable. Would I do something like show that $\int_{0}^{x^n}f(t)dt$ is bounded, and use the epsilon-delta to show the whole thing must be continuous (as in [Continuity of function consisting of an infinite series.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349570/continuity-of-function-consisting-of-an-infinite-series) for example)? I'm not sure how to do this rigorously though. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $$F(x):=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$ is Lipschitz, as one easily sees, since $|F(x)|\le \int_0^x|f|\le x\underset{[0,1]}{\text{sup}}(|f|)$. Let $K$ be its Lipschitz constant. Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left|\int_0^{x^n}f(t)dt\right|=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|F(x^n)|\le K\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=K\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Since the series is locally normally convergent and every term of the series is continuous, it is continuous.

One may ask if the method can be pushed further, i.e. if we can try to prove that the series is continuous also in $1$: this is not the case. Take $f(x)=x$ to find a counterexample.

Comment: A shame you gave the whole solution. I think it would have been a nice exercise for him to put the pieces together.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something silly but how did we conclude that the series is uniformly convergent?

Comment: @AryamanMaithani my bad, I was thinking about absolute convergence. Edited (however, we do have local normal convergence, but it seems irrelevant to add)

Comment: @Caffeine: I'm not sure I follow then. If all we have is absolute convergence, then can we conclude that the limit of a continuous series is continuous? I think something like $f_n(x) = x^n - x^{n+1}$ defined on $[0, 1]$ could prove to be a counterexample.

Comment: There is uniform convergence on each interval $[0,t]$ for $t<1$ by the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Nice counterexample! The series is locally normally convergent, in particular it is uniformly convergent on the compact subsets of $(0,1)$, and this suffices to prove continuity. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Caffeine thank you! How can you state though that $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt \leq x \sup f$? The way I see it, $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|dt \leq \int_{0}^{x}\sup|f(t)|dt=\sup|f(t)|\int_{0}^{x}1dt=x\sup|f(t)|$, not $x\sup f(t)$. How can we conclude that $x\sup|f(t)|$ exists?

Comment: @user1234544 that was a typo. The existence of the sup follows from the fact that $f$ has to be bounded to be Riemann integrable. Thus the image of $[0,1]$ through $|f$ is a bounded set, and by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ it must have a sup. However, the existence of a sup is not necessary here. As $|f|$ is bounded by some constant $M$, the lipschitzianity still follows, although the constant is not optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Let $t \in (0, 1)$. We first show that the series is continuous on $[0, t]$. First, note that $f$ must be bounded on $[0, 1]$ since it is Riemann integrable. Let $S = \sup |f|$.

We show that the sum converges uniformly on $[0, t]$. For this, we use Cauchy's criteria. That is, given any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $M \ge N \ge n$, we have

$$\sup_{x \in [0, t]}\left|\sum_{k=N}^M\int_0^{x^k}f(t)dt\right| \le \epsilon.$$

Of course, it suffices to show that the LHS of the above inequality can be made arbitrarily small.

For $x \in [0, t]$, we have

$$\left|\sum_{k=N}^M\int_0^{x^k}f(t)dt\right| \le \sum_{k=N}^M\int_0^{x^k}Sdt = S\sum_{k=N}^Mx^k \le S\sum_{k=N}^Mt^k.$$

The last summation can be made arbitrarily small since $\sum t^n$ converges. ($\because 0  < t < 1.$)

---

Thus, we have that $F(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\int_0^{x^n}f(t)dt$ is well-defined on $[0, 1)$ and is continuous on $[0, t]$ for every $t < 1$.

Now, we show that $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1)$. Let $x \in [0, 1)$. We show that $f$ is continous at $x$.
Choose $t$ such that $x < t < 1$. Then, $f$ is continuous on $[0, t]$ hence, continuous at $x$ and thus, we are done.